# careers.stackoverflow.com is broken

Tags: bug, design

As I am getting today, the styles of careers.stackoverflow.com seems broken. The home page and other pages all seems not getting the correct styles/scripts, I guess. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Any idea when we can expect it fixed?